# How to find field's value whose equal any value in array

Tags: go, rethinkdb

I have an array whose contain some ID :

```
["4007fa1c-4e27-4d2e-9429-f3631171760c",
"a21649a3-1a64-45cf-b92a-e899a7ef4742",
"1903a571-b166-4f93-9c1c-93dc66067a49", 
"2845d278-5ec4-45e9-ab9c-999178332c73",
"4e3ed481-a3d9-4689-8873-5c912668b26f",
"390e89fd-d680-4264-8806-8295b361d2f1"]
```

I would like thanks to this array, find all the posts having for "OriginID", one of the Ids present in the table.

I've started something like that, but I don't know how to complete to make work this code.

```
curs, _ =   r.Table("posts").
            Filter(r.Row.Field("Validated").Eq(false)).
Filter(func(customer r.Term) interface{}{
    for _, id := range listOriginID {
        //I don't know how to finish
    }
})
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: could you be more specific on the code sample ? A play link would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find yourself trying to iterate over an array inside a ReQL query, it is often easier or necessary to use built-in ReQL operations such as `Map` or `ConcatMap`.

In this case, `Contains` seems to be the operation you want. Try something like:

```
(...).Filter(func(post r.Term) interface{}{
    r.Expr(listOriginID).Contains(post.Field("OriginID"))
})
```